# AJAX: on success redirect then modify new page

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

This is probably really simple to do, but I can't seem to find the solution. I'm making an AJAX call, and on success I'm redirecting to a different page. That works.

**I want**: redirect > display message to user on new page

**I get**: display message to user on current page > redirect

Code:

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: delete_url ,
        data: {action_id: action_id } ,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                window.location = action_list
                $("#success").html(response.success);
            } else {
                $("#error").html(response.error);
                $("#success").html("");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a parameter in the query string to your success page.  Add to your `action_list` variable `?success=1`.  Then on your success page you can do a check to see if  `REQUEST["success"]` is `1` and if so, display the success message.