# Ajax wait till redirect to finish executing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have basically the same problem as the one described in the link below, but I dont find the solution to be very clear. I want my ajax success function to wait until  the window function   is finished executing, THEN modify the divs. Instead, it modifies the divs of the current page, then redirects. [AJAX: on success redirect then modify new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107393/ajax-on-success-redirect-then-modify-new-page)

```
main.js

$("#form").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#searchbar').val(); // store the form's data.   
        $.ajax({
                url: '/search',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id:id}, 
                dataType: 'text',


            success: function(data) {

                //Redirect to the page where we want to display the data
                window.location.href = '/test';


                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                $("#count").text("we analyzed...");
                $("#result1").text(data.county);
                $("#totals").text("with a score of..");
                $("#result2").text(data.totalSentiments);


   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     console.log("error")
     alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});

});
```

Comment: First of all if the window function completes execution then you are not in the same page - by definition. So the rest of code in ajax success will not be available. That means - you are not thinking in the right way. A possible solution is in the link you provided.

Comment: Implement the div modifications in callback

Comment: @JonathanLonowski What would be a more secure way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Will Suggest you Javascript [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) .

main.js

```
$("#form").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#searchbar').val(); // store the form's data.   
        $.ajax({
                url: '/search',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id:id}, 
                dataType: 'text',


            success: function(data) {

                //Redirect to the page where we want to display the data
                window.location.href = '/test';


                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                // Store
                localStorage.setItem("count", "we analyzed...");
                localStorage.setItem("result1", data.county);
                localStorage.setItem("totals", "with a score of..");
                localStorage.setItem("result2", data.totalSentiments);

   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     console.log("error")
     alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});

});
```

On Ready on same page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (localStorage.count) {
        $("#count").text(localStorage.count);
    }
    if (localStorage.result1) {
        $("#result1").text(localStorage.result1);
    }
    if (localStorage.totals) {
        $("#totals").text(localStorage.totals);
    }
    if (localStorage.result2) {
        $("#result2").text(localStorage.result2);
    }
});
```

Local Storage Store Data in Browser Storage. You Also Can Remove Data From Local Storage.

Comment: Your solution works! But the results that are displayed STAY there even if I navigate back to the home page, or even exit out of the site and load it again. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, For That you need to " localStorage.removeItem("count");" where you need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

setting the value of `location.href` will cause a full page refresh.

Therefore all your scripts will be wiped out.

If you REALLY wants to use the result of a ajax call to a redirected page, you should store this response data somewhere, then reuse it on your new page.

```
//save "data" in localSotorage
localStorage.myAjaxResponse = data; //if data is JSON then use: JSON.stringify(data) instead.
```

Then on your "/test" page, create a script to check for the value on the localStorage then display it.

```
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.myAjaxResponse);
    console.log(data);
    $("#count").text("we analyzed...");
    $("#result1").text(data.county);
    $("#totals").text("with a score of..");
    $("#result2").text(data.totalSentiments);
```

Although, there are other better ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: What ways are you thinking of? and what is myAjaxResponse?

Comment: `myAjaxResponse` is any name for your variable. you can use localStorage.WHATEVER = "what ever value".

Comment: Got it. By add a script on /test, you mean put the code above inside <script = text/javascript> at the top of the /test page? I tried that and nothing happened

Comment: Open Console in Chrome Web Inspection and type: "localStorage.myAjaxResponse". check if there are any value there. If there isn't, you ajax success function is not setting it properly. If there is, your new function in "/test" is not picking it up correctly.

Comment: There is data there, the correct data. So what could be wrong with /test?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

On your ajax success:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
window.location.href = '/test?county='+data.county+'&sentiment='+totalSentiments;
```

Then on your `test` page write in javascript block:

```
   var params={};
   window.location.search
          .replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
            params[key] = value;
          }
        );
    if (params.length > 0) {
        $("#count").text("we analyzed...");
        $("#result1").text(params['county']);
        $("#totals").text("with a score of..");
        $("#result2").text(params['sentiments']);
    }
```